# Calculate the $F^{−1}$ of a function

Tags: real-analysis, discrete-mathematics, functions, stochastic-processes, recreational-mathematics

Let $V:=\{x \in \mathbb{R}:-5 \leq x \leq 5\} .$ Consider the function $F: V \rightarrow V$ defined by
$$
F(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}
-1, & \text { if }-5 \leq x \leq 1 \\
2, & \text { if } 1<x \leq 3 \\
0, & \text { if } 3<x<4 \\
x, & \text { if } 4 \leq x \leq 5
\end{array}\right.
$$

$I:=\{x\in\mathbb{R}\ :\ -5\leq x\leq1\}$. Choose the set that $F^{−1}(I)$ is equal to.

Answer (score 1):

Of all the  possible values of $F$ the only value in $(0,4)$ is $2$. Hence, $F^{-1}(I)=\{x: F(x) \in (0,4)\}=(1,3]$. The correct answer is b).

For  the edited version of the question $F^{-1}(I)=[-5,1] \cup (3,4)$.

Comment: I am extremely sorry to put the wrong interval for I. I have updated. Could you please update your answer please.

Comment: @ElizabethJ.Magee I have updated my answer. Once again a), c),d),e) are all false.

Comment: I got [-5,1] part. but how u got (3,4]. Could you please explain?

Comment: For $x \in (3,4)$, $F(x)=0$ and $0$ lies  in $I$. @ElizabethJ.Magee

Comment: That I missed. Thanks a lot for your clear explanation.